# Функция getche()

Tags: c++

Есть 2 примера программы. в первоем примере требуется обязательно указать ch определенное значение

```
int main()
{
    int chcount = 0;
    int wdcount = 1;
    char ch = 'a';              //ch должна иметь определенное значение
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    while (ch != '\r')
    {
        ch = _getche();
        if (ch == ' ')
            wdcount++;
        else
            chcount++;
    }
    cout << "\nСлов: " << wdcount << endl;
    cout << "Букв: " << (chcount-1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

во втором примере уже не требуется присваивать ch значение

```
int main()
{
    int chcount = 0;
    int wdcount = 1;
    char ch;                          // уже без символа 'a'    
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    while ((ch=_getche()) != '\r')
    {
        if (ch == ' ')
            wdcount++;
        else
            chcount++;
    }
    cout << "\nСлов: " << wdcount << endl;
    cout << "Букв: " << chcount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Это из книги ООП C++ Лафоре 113 страница
https://books.google.by/books?id=vUXt0ZJD600C&lpg=PP1&hl=ru&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=true

Уже перечитываю не один раз эту главу и не могу понять почему именно в этом участке требуется указать значение ch

Если убрать значение у ch в первом примере то тогда компилятор ругается на ошибку 
cpp(15): error C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "ch"

немного погуглив:

> Инициализация означает, что переменная запущена в работу, ей присвоено
>   начальное значение, она инициализирована. Без присвоения начального
>   значения переменная просто объявлена, а с начальным значением она еще
>   и инициализирована.

Остается вопрос какой участок кода требует инициализации переменной ch?
По логике осмелюсь предположить строчка ch = _getche(); требует инициализации от char ch = 'a';  но не уверен

Comment: Инициализация требуется для использования значения переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Ну в первом примере вы в цикле, в начале, пытаетесь  проверить значение неинициализированной переменной `ch`. Строка

```
while (ch != '\r')
```

Запрашивает проверку по сути неинициализированной переменной(если конечно вы не пишете `char ch = 'a'`) это и вызывает ошибку, и слава богу, я вам скажу.

Comment: тоесть while (ch != '\r') в начале получает значение 'a' сравнивает ее с условием что она не является '\r' и уже в последующем получает остальные значение от _getche() ?

Comment: @FaTaL да, а если вы не заполняете переменную при создании, вы по сути пытаетесь проверить пустоту(точнее там будет какой-то мусор из памяти, н это не важно), это и вызывает ошибку.